# Creating Mock for Sort Header Event Angular Material

Tags: angular, angular-material, jasmine, angular-unit-test

I am trying to write a unit test for a matSortChange function. This emits a Sort Event that I thought was just an object with an active property and direction property.
My test currently looks like:

```
it('sort unit test', () => {
 const fakeSortEvent = {active: 'fakeActive', direction: 'asc'};
 component.saveSort(fakeSortEvent);

})
```

The TS error I am getting is

```
Types of property 'direction' are incompatible.
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'SortDirection'
```

When looking up what SortDirection looks like [angular material docs](https://material.angular.io/components/sort/api#type_aliases), it seems like my fakeSortEvent object should work. How can I create a mock Sort Event?

Comment: As error says, direction could not be type of string, it should be type of StringDirection that could be 'asc', 'desc' or ' '. More about that you can see it [here](https://material.angular.io/components/sort/api#SortDirection)

Comment: So SortDirection just being a string of either 'asc' | 'desc' | ' ', shouldn't the fakeSortEvent I created work? giving direction 'asc'?

Comment: Yes you are right, this should work.

Can you try create fakeSortEvent like this:
```const fakeSortEvent: Sort = {active: 'fakeActive', direction: 'asc'}```.

I don't know if this will work, but you can try it.

Comment: OMG! that worked...... Thank you @diabolique. Going to call it for the day after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank @diabolique for the answer in the commments. Adding type Sort to fakeSortEvent has it working. Code:

```
it('sort unit test', () => {
 const fakeSortEvent: Sort = {active: 'fakeActive', direction: 'asc'};
 component.saveSort(fakeSortEvent);
})
```